# Navigation bar hidden behind map

Tags: javascript, html, css, uinavigationbar

A mate and I are working on our hunting based website.

[Hunting spots NZ](http://huntingspots.co.nz/gareth/spots.html)

So while this is a work in progress, I am stuck on a particular issue.
I've attempted to add as this example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.content').toggleClass('isOpen');
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700');
@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font: 12px/1 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #333;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.content.isOpen {
  transform: translate3d(220px,0,0);
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:before {
  content: '\f0c9';
  font: 42px fontawesome;
}

/* Demo Navigation */

.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  background: #2a2a2a;
}

.nav li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}

.nav li a:before {
  font: 14px fontawesome;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  left: 20px;
}

.nav li:nth-child(1) a:before { content: '\f00a'; }
.nav li:nth-child(2) a:before { content: '\f012'; }
.nav li:nth-child(3) a:before { content: '\f0e8'; }
.nav li:nth-child(4) a:before { content: '\f0c3'; }
.nav li:nth-child(5) a:before { content: '\f022'; }
.nav li:nth-child(6) a:before { content: '\f115'; }
.nav li:nth-child(7) a:before { content: '\f085'; }
.nav li:nth-child(8) a:before { content: '\f023'; left: 23px; }

.nav li a:hover {
  background: #444;
}

.nav li a.active {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 #5b5, inset 6px 0 0 #222;
  background: #444;
}

/* Demo Description */

h1 {
  margin: 25px 0 15px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <div class='title'>
      Sidebar
    </div>
    <ul class='nav'>
      <li>
        <a>Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Statistics</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class='active'>Milestones</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Experiments</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Previews</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Assets</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='content isOpen'>
    <a class='button'></a>
    <h1>Flexbox Off Canvas Menu</h1>
    <h2>Lightweight, simple, easy to use</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

However I either it's hidden behind the map, or doesn't show at all or isn't animated. 
So my question is, how do I add the example in the above link to my site?
Any help would be awesome.

Comment: You need to include a reference to jquery in your exampe.  $ is not defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Could you maybe explain that like I am five. I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful : https://code.jquery.com/. Add a script tag referecing the jquery library.